# Trying to combine snow material with object (gone wrong!)

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I've got a snow material, following this guy's tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fcDFntILn0M

You can see here that the material itself works ok:
[image]

But when I apply it to the ground, it turns into a shiny ice, like the uv's are messed up (I don't really understand uv mapping properly).

I imported a section of a minecraft world:
[image]

I tried merge by distance to clean up the mesh, pretty sure that made it worse.

What can I do to simplify the mesh and apply the snow correctly?

Comment: Difficult to tell from those images, but it looks as if you need to increase the roughness so that it doesn't reflect the sky.